# Laravel model and controller interaction

Tags: php, mvc, laravel

I want to know if I'm going about creating and calling two functions from my model to my controller in the simplest and cleanest way.

Model:

```
public function getPosts()
{
    $post = $this->paginate(4);
    return $post;
}

public function getMonth($post)
{
    $post->month = date('M', strtotime($this->created_at));
    $post->month = strtoupper($post->month);
    return $post->month;
}

public function getDay($post)
{
    $post->day = date('d', strtotime($this->created_at));
    return $post->day;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $post = $this->post->getPosts();
    $post->month = $this->post->getMonth($post);
    $post->day = $this->post->getDay($post);

    return View::make('posts.index', compact('post'));
}
```

I am unsure about if my controller is acting in a strict MVC way, being that I thought it's only job is to direct traffic, but it's doing more by calling functions from my model. Is this the best way to go about this?

Comment: please include your full class so that we can see if you have done other declaration and setting and if you are extending certain classes or not - because if you are not using eloquent you have to let us know and maybe we can critic a bit more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP is not my area of expertise, so just some generic notes:

1. `4` is a magic number here:

   > ```
   > $post = $this->paginate(4);
   > ```

   Why is it 4? What the purpose if this number? A named constant or local variable would be readable with a descriptive name.
2. > ```
   > public function getMonth($post)
   > {
   >     $post->month = date('M', strtotime($this->created_at));
   >     $post->month = strtoupper($post->month);
   >     return $post->month;
   > }
   > ```

   Using a local variable with a proper name, like `lowercase_month`, in the first line would be readable and more descriptive.
3. These methods violates *Command Query Separation* since they return some data and modify the `$post` too.

   > Functions should either do something or answer something, but not both.

   Source: *Clean Code by Robert C. Martin*, *Chapter 3: Functions*, *Command Query Separation* p45
4. > ```
   > $post->month = date('M', strtotime($this->created_at));
   > $post->month = strtoupper($post->month);
   > ```

   I'd consider moving these calls to the `Post` class since it seems [data envy](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DataEnvy). (Pseudocode.)

   ```
   class Post {
       ...
       public void setMonth($created_at) {
           $lowercase_month = date('M', strtotime($created_at));
           $post->month = strtoupper($lowercase_month);
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

### Model

- I have never seen a paginator inside a model in Laravel (and if it was it wouldn't be named something so vague as a method). It's always in the controller. If you find yourself using the number 4 a lot for the number of user in different controllers, by all means store it here as a constant.
- Stop writing returns needlessly on two lines, so no more `$that = x; return $that;`, only `return x;`.
- I found `getMonth` and `getDay` intensely confusing. Does it even run like that? Instead, rewrite them to return the month and day of that particular model instance.
- They should probably also be renamed to `getMonthCreated`/`getDayCreated`, or something assuming there's some other date on the model like `updated_at`, which there almost certainly is. (I was too lazy to do this.)
- Use Carbon to your advantage to get the month and day in your format. Take advantage of the [automatic date casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting).

```php
public function getMonth()
{
    return strtoupper($this->created_at->format('M'));
}

public function getDay()
{
    return $this->created_at->format('d');
}
```

### Controller

- Use the `view` helper because it's less code and no import.
- Don't use `compact` so it's on one line, yet it doesn't harm the readability. Plus it's easier to find typos without it as your variable name won't be a string.
- Use the plural `posts`, as it's an array of more than one post.
- What exactly is up with `$this->post`? Why does `$this` have a `post` instead of rewriting to use `Model::getPosts()`?
- I removed the part where you get month/day as it's so weird. Go change your view to handle it more naturally.

```php
public function index()
{
    return view('posts.index', ['posts' => Model::paginate(4)]);
}
```

### View

- I have no idea what you're doing here, but a good guess is that you loop through the posts and display the date of each:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
  Month: {{ $post->getMonth() }}<br>
  Day: {{ $post->getDay() }}
@endforeach
```

If you're putting the day and month exactly next to each other, then you should redesign a whole bunch of the code and just use `$post->created_at->format('M d')` (or similar).

---

### Bonus

Give all your methods [return types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php). If you have any accepting parameters, make sure those have types declared too. (This is modern PHP not available when the question was posted.)